# Can a (member) function defined in a header have different definition depending on where it is included? Is this well defined?

Tags: c++, optimization, language-lawyer

Let's say I have something like this in a library header:

```
// ExampleLib.h

#ifndef DEFAULT_OPTION_VALUE
#  define DEFAULT_OPTION_VALUE 1
#endif

class Example {
public:
    void doSomething ();
private:
    static bool getDefaultOptionValue () {
        return (0 != DEFAULT_OPTION_VALUE);
    } 
};
```

And something like this in a library source file:

```
#include <ExampleLib.h>

void Example::doSomething () {
    ...
    if (getDefaultOptionValue()) {
       ...
    } else {
       ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Now, let's say when an application that links to this library is built, it `#defines` its own value for `DEFAULT_OPTION_VALUE` via the compiler command line or whatever (which may differ from the value set when compiling the library), with the intended effect being to allow the application to determine the behavior of `doSomething()` at compile time.

My main question is: Is this even valid (and would it behave as intended), or is it undefined behavior?

Then, if it *is* well-defined, is there any risk that a compiler, when compiling the *library*, would optimize away the effect of changing the `#define`, such as:

- ... seeing that `Example::getDefaultOptionValue()` returns a constant, and therefore optimizing away the call to `getDefaultOptionValue()` from the implementation of `doSomething()`, and/or
- ... inlining `Example::getDefaultOptionValue()` when compiling `doSomething()`
- ... etc.

And, as a consequence, the behavior wouldn't reflect the value of `DEFAULT_OPTION_VALUE` set when the application itself is built?

Not sure if it matters, but assume C++14 or later.

Comment: If you change the value of that define between the compilation of the library and some application you'll be in trouble no matter what. So, why do you even need this? Either make this a constant `constexpr value = 1` OR take that as a parameter for your class and allow different users to provide it.

Comment: @al3c If I do `constexpr bool value = DEFAULT_OPTION_VALUE` as a class member; and the value changes between library and application compilations, will I still be in the same type of trouble?

Comment: compiler optimizations are not allowed to change observable behavior (unless explicitly allowed, eg copy elision). Typically optimizations do change observable behavior when your code has undefined behavior, but then optimizations are the lesser problem

Comment: yes, if its not a constant make it a variable otherwise one way or another you'll violate the ODR and have undefined behaviour

Comment: Is there any reason to make it `constexpr volatile bool` instead?

Comment: maybe a better title is "Is this undefined behavior?" and when the answer is no, you need not worry about optimizations getting in your way.

Comment: @JasonC nope you are still defining 2 different versions of `getDefaultOptionValue`.

Comment: You have ODR violation if library and application doesn't have same definition.

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 That makes a lot more sense, thanks; tried to edit this into something more reasonable. Also *tentatively* added [tag:language-lawyer].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **[basic.def.odr]/6** There can be more than one definition of a class type ... in a program provided that each definition appears in a different translation unit, and provided the definitions satisfy the following requirements. Given such an entity named `D` defined in more than one translation unit, then
>
> (6.1) — each definition of `D` shall consist of the same sequence of tokens...
> ...
>
> If the definitions of `D` do not satisfy these requirements, then the behavior is undefined.

If `DEFAULT_OPTION_VALUE` expands to a different sequence of tokens in two translation units that include the definition of `Example`, then the program that combines these translation units would exhibit undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Being a textual substitution, there is nothing maintaining the link to the name `DEFAULT_OPTION_VALUE`.  The preprocessor changes the source file to read:

```
return (0 != 1);
```

and when the library is compiled, it sees that definition.

When the same header file is used in the main project with a different definition for `DEFAULT_OPTION_VALUE`, it compiles to a different function body *in that translation unit*.

If this is linked using plain libraries (a collection of object files), it is clearly undefined behavior.  I do expect that compilers will both inline the function in each place it is used, so it can't do linker-choose-one for the whole program.  I also expect it to indeed optimize out the statements because of constant values known at compile time.

Answer (score 1):

> Is this undefined behavior

As per the quoted rule in Igor's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67406134/2079303), this is an ODR violation. That violation makes the program ill-formed (no diagnostic required). This is effectively the same as having UB.

> and, if so, can I fix it?

You could use a non-member function which allows you to declare the function with internal linkage. If you do that, then each translation unit will have an identical class declaration and each will declare a separate function, and thus the declarations being different would not be an issue. Confusingly, the keyword to declare a function with internal linkage is the same as the one used for static member functions. You just declare it outside the class:

```
namespace detail {
    static bool getDefaultOptionValue () {
        return (0 != DEFAULT_OPTION_VALUE);
    }
}

class Example;
```

Since your member function was private, I've put the function in a namespace `detail`, which is a conventional way to express "This is private, here be dragons".